# http SAML get request not redirecting to a url location

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, saml-2.0, passport-saml

I'm using passport-saml and trying to get my redirect working on get request. But the response that I get from server is pure HTML. How do I make it load the HTML in a new page?

```
this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/login/saml',{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((response) =>{console.log("saml response",response); Response.redirect(response)}, error =>{console.log(" saml error",error)})
```

I am getting entire html page as response, whereas I want the page to redirect to the url location for login.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is authenticate response you are getting?

Comment: what is html response are you getting ? can you modify it.
if you can modify it you can write simple html with javacript which will redirect to desired page example :- 
`<h1>Please Wait Redirecting </h1>
                    <a id="purchastStatusLink" href="${purchastStatusLink}"></a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('purchastStatusLink').click();</script>`

Comment: @Saurabh47g i cant change the html its coming from SAML authentication provider